# JavaScript Bind Event at Certain Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I'm trying to implement the following functionality and am having some trouble. What I want is when a user clicks a certain image, a popup div will appear containing some information about that image. Then if the user were to click anywhere on the page outside of that popup div, it would simply hide and then remove the popup.

What I am trying to do is register an eventListener after the popUp div is added to the page. Tried with both jquery and without and am after the same issue. (I included both below but only one is active in the code at a time.)

```
    createProfilePopUpEventListener: function(){
        $('body').on('click', function(){
           $('.profile_pop_up').fadeOut('fast').remove();
        });
    },

    createProfilePopUpEventListener: function(){
        var el = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        el.addEventListener("click", $('.profile_pop_up').fadeOut('fast').remove();
    },

    showPopUp: function(e){
         //creates popUp and adds it to the DOM
         this.createProfilePopUpEventListener();
    }
```

What seems to be happening is that the event is being triggered right away on the initial click to show the popup and thus it is never displayed. How can I create an eventListener that only starts listening for those clicks at a certain time?

Comment: my guess is actually that your problem is that your functions appear to be named the same thing, so the second one overwrites the first.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is event propagation. Your image that is used as the trigger to open the popup bubbles your event up the whole DOM, eventually to the body. Thus the fadeout/remove event is triggered at the same time as your open event.

You will need to stop the propagation of that in such a fashion (using :

```
$('#popup_trigger').on('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('.profile_pop_up').fadeIn();
});
```